# memberNames in ValidationResult not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am performing some model validation via a model validator attached to the model at class level. If I find an error I need to be able to attach that error to the relevant field in the view so that it can be shown clearly to the user.

However simply passing in memberNames to the ValidationResult doesn't do anything. Instead what I have found is that I need to re-validate in the controller in order to then populate the ModelState object.

Here is the code:

```
public class CompletedMilestoneInCorrectOrderAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Milestones cannot be completed out of sequence";

    public CompletedMilestoneInCorrectOrderAttribute()
        : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = (RevisionEditViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        var previousCompleted = true;
        var loop = 0;
        var members = new List<string>();

        foreach (var rm in model.RevisionMilestones)
        {
            if (rm.Completed && !previousCompleted)
            {
                members.Add("revisionMilestones[" + loop + "].ExpectedCompletionDate");
                members.Add("revisionMilestones[" + loop + "].Completed");
            }

            if (!rm.NotApplicable)
            {
                previousCompleted = rm.Completed;
            }

            loop++;
        }

        if (members.Any())
        {
            return new ValidationResult(DefaultErrorMessage, members);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And in the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(RevisionEditViewModel model)
    {
        //without this code the error never gets attached to the correct field in the view
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults);
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            foreach (var memberName in validationResult.MemberNames)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            *snip*
        }
        else
        {
            *snip*
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what is going on? How can I correct it so the messy code in the controller is no longer needed?

Cheers Mike

Comment: Have you considered using the IValidatableObject interface? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: Two reasons; firstly I doubt it would make any difference as that interface still uses ValidationResult to return validation errors. Secondly I don't like that pattern, models, in my opinion, should be clean and validation should be something that is applied to them, not an integral part of the class.

Comment: Can you post your view and model? I strongly suspect that something isnt being included in the postback, because the validation should be being called.

Comment: Sorry, I am no longer working on that project so I can't post any more code.